# Route 53 and Certificate Manager Issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

Is anyone else having issues getting a route 53 domain name certified using the certificate manager? I'm following the documentation very closely and am running into a block where I request a certificate through DNS and then create the records in route 53, but I'm stuck pending validation for days. When I click the "Create Records in Route 53 button" the records are created in route 53, but nothing else happens. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

The hosted zone is firstlast.com and I'm trying to certify [www.firstlast.com](http://www.firstlast.com) and firstlast.com (not actually firstlast, some other name haha).

I followed this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html

I've also tried email validation but they don't give you a CNAME and it's unclear how to integrate with route 53.

Comment: "I've also tried email validation but they don't give you a CNAME and it's unclear how to integrate with route 53." Email validation doesn't use DNS, it uses Email, so it wouldn't have CNAMES or integrate with Route53...  Question: Where did you purchase the domain name? Is Route53 actually configured as the DNS provider for this domain name, or did you just go into Route53 and create a new hosted zone?

Answer (score 1):

Mark B had the correct answer. I had to copy/paste the name servers from the hosted zone into the name servers -> domain name servers.

Answer (score 0):

Use an online tool to check if your CNAME records can be pulled.

I use this: https://mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx

If you cannot see the value displayed in *AWS Certificate Manager*, check that the **nameservers** are configured correctly.

Sometimes Route 53 doesn't set up these nameservers from the *Hosted zone* (if your domain is also in AWS). Never edit the *nameservers* from the hosted zone, edit the ones from your provider were the domain have been purchased.